# What intuition stands behind implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, education, implicit-differentiation

I'm trying to undestand implicit differentation

Let's take as a an example equation y^2 + x^2 = 1

**1. How i think about how the equation works**

I think the function as : if x changes then the y term have to hold value of "y^2 + x^2" equal 1. Therefore the equation defines some set of numbers at x cordinates and y cordinates.

**2. How i think about how differentate the equation**

1. If i want to know how the equation changes as x changes, i'm taking
   derivative with respect to x
2. $\frac{d}{dx}y^2+\frac{d}{dx}x^2=\frac{d}{dx}1$
3. We can consider $y$ as a function, $y = f(x)$
4. Therefore: $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))^2+\frac{d}{dx}x^2=\frac{d}{dx}1$
5. We can calculate how (f(x))^2 changes as f(x) changes, using chain rule.
6. $\frac{df(x)}{dx}\frac{d}{df(x)}(f(x))^2+\frac{d}{dx}x^2=\frac{d}{dx}1$
7. This is equal: $2f(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx}f(x)+\frac{d}{dx}x^2=\frac{d}{dx}1$
8. As $x$ changes, $x^2$ changes as $2x$, therefore $2f(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx}f(x)+2x=\frac{d}{dx}1$
9. As x changes, 1 doesn't changes, therefore it is 0.  $2f(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx}f(x)+2x=0$
10. We don't know derivative of $f(x)$ but we can solve it
11. If we solve the derivative, we get $f'(x) = -\frac xy$

**3. Questions**

1. My way of thinking is right?
2. What does mean the final answer? It looks strange, it doesn't tell me nothing comparing to norma, explicit derivative of a function.
3. There is a difference between $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}y$ ?
4. Why i want to know ? Because i want to know how to interpretate steps and solution, not only algorithmically solve some book's problems.

PS. I'm barely after highschool - Therefore i don't know yet set theorem and other high level math things. I'm learning calculus on my own.

Comment: In your example, **very** informally let $dy$ be the change in $y$ and $dx$ the change in $x^2$. Then the change in $y^2$ is roughly $2y\,dy$ and the change in $x^2$ is roughly $2x\,dx$. But the sum of the changes is $0$. So $2y\,dy=2x\,dx$. Solving we get $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2y}{2x}$. Of course this is "wrong," $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not a fraction, but using the language of limits we can produce a justified version.

Comment: To answer another of your questions, the implicit form does tell you a lot. It says that the slope of the tangent line to $x^2+y^2=1$ at $(x,y)$ has slope $-\frac{2y}{2x}$.

Comment: @André Nicolas
But does domain of $\frac{−2y}{2x}$ is restricted to function's domain? Because $y^2+x^2=1$ is not defines for x,y>1.

Comment: Sure, there are restrictions, we have $x^2+y^2=1$, and we have to be cautious about interpreting the result for $y=0$ (I have typos/errors above, of course it is $-\frac{2x}{2y}$.

Comment: If we differentiate with respect to x, and y is a function of x, then how it is possible that  derivative of the equation is depend on y ?

Comment: It can depend on the value of $y$ through the dependence of $y$ on $x$. However, in the case $x^2+y^2=1$, $y$ is not a function of $x$, for if $x=1/2$, there are two possible values of $y$. I prefer to think of $x^2+y^2=1$ as a *relationship* between variables $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3):

As a first thought, consider a parametrization of some part of the solution set as $t \mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ for $t \in [a,b]$. Suppose both $x(t), y(t)$ are differentiable with respect to $t$. Then we have the equation:

$$x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 = 1$$

Which becomes, differentiating with respect to $t$

$$2x(t)x'(t) + 2y(t)y'(t) = 0$$

Assuming $x' \neq 0, y \neq 0$, we have

$$-\frac{x(t)}{y(t)} = \frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}$$

So we've related the coordinates of the parametrization and the derivatives of the coordinates. A particularly nice case would be if $x(t) = t$, in which case we can thing of it as $y(x)$ and the right side is $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

What's really going on here is the study of the level set of some function $F(x,y)$. One way of seeing this is that if a smooth path $t \mapsto(x(t),y(t))$ traverses a level set then the composition $F(x(t),y(t)) = k$ is constant, so it's derivative is zero. The multivariable chain rule gives use relationships between $x,y,x',y'$ in terms of $F$. The implicit function theorem tells us that under some simple conditions on $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x},  \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$we can locally solve in such a way as to parametrize with $x(t) = x$, so basically $y(t) =y(x)$. Then $x' = 1$ and the relation gets simpler.

I meant to add this, but the "condition" is simply that $
y'(t) \perp \Delta F(\gamma(t))$

Comment: I don't know yet set theorem(look at bottom of question),  i'll ask some questions.
What is $t↦(x(t),y(t))$ It look like "t maps to a certain cordinate".
$t∈[a,b]$ it means that "t is member of set between a and b"?
The last paragraph is not understandable for me.

Comment: Yeah, so the notation means that we're basically running $t$ (think of it as time) from $t= a$ to $t=b$ where $a < b$ are real numbers. $t \mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ means that $x,y$ are changing depending on $t$, so it's describing a point moving around the plane over time.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as nudge both side of the equation and do the derivative.

Example:
For function,

$$y^q = x^p$$

If you increase $x \to x + \Delta x $ then $y \to y+\Delta y $

Or,

$$ (y+ \Delta   y)^q = ( x+ \Delta x )^p$$

Now substract this from original eqn

$$ (y+ \Delta y  )^q - y^q = 
(x+ \Delta x)^p - x^p$$
divide both side by $\Delta x $

$$ \frac{ (y+ \Delta y )^q - y^q }{ \Delta x}=\frac{ (x+ \Delta x)^p - x^p}{\Delta x}$$

Now on left side,

$$ \frac{ (y+ \Delta x  )^q - y^q }{ \Delta x} =  \frac{ (y+ \Delta x  )^q - y^q }{ \Delta y} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$

Now taking limit on both side of equation as the deltas drop down to zero. You get derivatives!

i.e:

$$ qy^{q-1} \frac{dy}{dx} = px^{p-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

The way I think about it reflects a marginally different perspective on the derivative itself.  Essentially, I view the fundamental operation as the "differential", and the derivative is merely the ratio of two differentials.  For a general overview of how I teach this, you can see my [arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03459).  For a more theoretical version of the justification for this, see [Fite's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07958).

Imagine that every variable in your equation is dependent on some "invisible" variable, let's call it $q$.  Therefore, $x$ is actually $x(q)$ and $y$ is actually $y(q)$.  The differential operator $d()$ takes its parameter and evaluates it at $q$ and $q + \epsilon$ (where $\epsilon$ is a fixed hyperreal infinitesimal value).  So to expand standard notation, $dx = d(x)$ which is actually $d(x(q)) = x(q + \epsilon) - x(q)$.

Since we are just doing differentials and not derivatives, you can take the differential of anything.  You don't have a variable that you are differentiating "with respect to", and therefore there is no denominator.  So, $d(x^2) = 2x\,dx$; $d(xy) = x\,dy + y\,dx$; $d(xyz) = xy\,dz + xz\,dy + yz\,dx$; and so forth.  There is no limit to the number of variables or where they are in the equation.  Just use standard rules, but don't divide by $dx$.

Then, if you wish, you can solve for any derivative (i.e., ratio of differentials) that you want.

In this methodology, there is no difference between explicit differentiation, implicit differentiation, and multivariable differentiation.  They all follow the exact same pattern.

So, for $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, you can simply differentiate both sides:

$$d(x^2 + y^2) = d(1) \\
d(x^2) + d(y^2) = d(1) \\
2x\,dx + 2y\, dy = 0$$

Now, we can algebraically solve for any derivative we wish.  If we want to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ we just manipulate for it:

$$ 2x\,dx + 2y\, dy = 0 \\
2y\,dy = -2x\,dx \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-2x}{2y} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x}{y} $$

For me, this combines both the intuitive and the operational approach.  They are one and the same.  It just requires an adjustment on what you view the differential and the derivative to be.  If the differential is just a subtraction between two infinitesimally-close points of a presumed independent variable, then all of the basic rules just fall out, as well as the ability to do algebraic manipulations.

Comment: If $d(f(x))=f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)$ for $\varepsilon$ infenitesimal hyperreal then value of this depends on chosing of $\varepsilon$. Also in hyperreals $Adx-Bdy=0$ doesn't mean in hyperreals that $y'=A/B$ because derivative here is standard part of the fraction.  $f'(x)=st\frac{f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)}{\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon$  infenitesimal (if derivative exist value of standard part function is same for any infenitesimal $\varepsilon$).